# Get value of textbox with java sciprt c#, When the text is in runat="server"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i am building a website for my clients, in my site they need to request an help form.

in this form i will like to check the textboxes in java sciprt code.

but, when i am trying to do this code:

```
var nameeee = document.getElementById("name");
on this textbox:
<asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" CssClass="name"></asp:TextBox>
```

its just not working... i am trying to get the value of it but its seemds to not work. i am gussing its because the ruant="server", i need it so i can call it from my C# code.

Any help?

Thanks, 
(Sorry for bad english)
Alon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get value:

```
var nameeee = document.getElementById("<%=name.ClientID%>").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have this instead:

```
var nameeee = document.getElementById("<%=name.ClientID%>");
```

This will give you the actual ID of the textbox.

Comment: make sure you call the code after the element has been specified. eg. wrapping it within $(document).ready(function(){}); method

Comment: The code you posted (and I fixed) give pointer to the textbox itself. To get its value, read its value property as ysrb showed in his [own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952062/get-value-of-textbox-with-java-sciprt-c-when-the-text-is-in-runat-server/7952133#7952133).